# Exception handling for Endpoints in wso2

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 EI.

Task: I am sending a message to Endpoint queue  and if the  endpoint queue is not reachable, I have to retry  for 3 times and still its not reachable then I have to send message to another queue.

Approach: I got many links in Stack Overflow.
I am using below code in my endpoint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="DestinationEndPoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="jms:/TARGET?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://192.168.1.33:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
    <timeout>
               <duration>30000</duration>
               <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
           </timeout>
           <suspendOnFailure>
               <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
               <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
               <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
               <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
           </suspendOnFailure>
           <markForSuspension>
           <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
               <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
           </markForSuspension>

</endpoint>
```

I have given the wrong IP  so that while sending message it will fail.
But the issue is at 1st trial only its sending the message to error queue, but I have to retry for 3 times and then I have to send to  error queue.

Can you please give me any suggestions?